# Clear URL with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo, url-rewriting, html5boilerplate

I am pretty new to webdesign and haven't been able to figure this one out..

I am using HTML5Boilerplate as a template for my new website. The .htaccess file that ships with the template rewrites "www.example.com -> example.com". This is fine with me.

Now I would like to rewrite all my /index.html -> root folder and clear the slash at the end.

E.g.: when someone types or a link directs to "www.mysite.com/subfolder/index.html" (or .htm) this would get rewritten as "mysite.com/subfolder".

The code is at the moment:

```
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Start rewrite engine
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Turning on the rewrite engine is necessary for the following rules and

# features. FollowSymLinks must be enabled for this to work.

# Some cloud hosting services require RewriteBase to be set: goo.gl/HOcPN
# If using the h5bp in a subdirectory, use `RewriteBase /foo` instead where
# 'foo' is your directory.

# If your web host doesn't allow the FollowSymlinks option, you may need to
# comment it out and use `Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch`, but be aware of the
# performance impact: http://goo.gl/Mluzd

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
# Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
  RewriteEngine On
# RewriteBase /
</IfModule>

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Suppress or force the "www." at the beginning of URLs
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# The same content should never be available under two different URLs -
# especially not with and without "www." at the beginning, since this can cause
# SEO problems (duplicate content). That's why you should choose one of the
# alternatives and redirect the other one.

# By default option 1 (no "www.") is activated.
# no-www.org/faq.php?q=class_b

# If you'd prefer to use option 2, just comment out all option 1 lines
# and uncomment option 2.

# IMPORTANT: NEVER USE BOTH RULES AT THE SAME TIME!

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Option 1:
# Rewrite "www.example.com -> example.com".

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Option 2:
# Rewrite "example.com -> www.example.com".
# Be aware that the following rule might not be a good idea if you use "real"
# subdomains for certain parts of your website.

# <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
#   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
#   RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
# </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're serious about working with HTAccess, there is a very solid reference that will solve all the little thngs that might come up. It's not free - but will pay for itself.

http://htaccessbook.com

Comment: Hi, David, and thanks for the tip, but I don't think I'm going to go into that much details with htaccess. I just need this one little thing fixed and then forget about tweaking the htaccess file.

Comment: Its not that compicated - but you can get into the worst trouble doing something where you dont' understand the details, which would be impossible to expalin properly in a post on this one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*\/index\.html?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.html?$ "/$1" [R=301,L]
```

To remove the end slash add this code:

```
# remove trailing slash
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(\?.*)?$ $1$2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: No, didn't help. Atleast if you put that after the 

`# Rewrite "www.example.com -> example.com".

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>`

that already exists in my code.